# I have an ATL project with proxy-stub support enabled, where can I find the implementation of all the methods in xdlldata.h file?

Tags: c++, dll, proxy, atl, stub

```
my generated xdlldta.h file 

#ifdef _MERGE_PROXYSTUB

extern "C" 
{
BOOL WINAPI PrxDllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, 
    LPVOID lpReserved);
STDAPI PrxDllCanUnloadNow(void);
STDAPI PrxDllGetClassObject(REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, LPVOID* ppv);
STDAPI PrxDllRegisterServer(void);
STDAPI PrxDllUnregisterServer(void);
}

#endif
```

Here, I do not think that the implementation of these methods is a part of my project, and I want to specifically check the implementation of

```
BOOL WINAPI PrxDllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, 
    LPVOID lpReserved);
```

Where can I find the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xlldata.c defines `ENTRY_PREFIX`:

```
#define ENTRY_PREFIX    Prx
```

and then includes dlldata.c, which is generated by MIDL compiler:

```
#include "dlldata.c"
```

The generated dlldata.c file includes SDK rpcproxy.h:

```
#include <rpcproxy.h>
```

rpcproxy.h in turn looks at the `ENTRY_PREFIX`, it actually even has some short syntax help in its header.

This is where PrxDllMain is defined:

```
/*DllMain saves the DLL module handle for later use by DllRegisterServer */ \
BOOL WINAPI DLLMAIN_ENTRY( \
    HINSTANCE  hinstDLL, \
    DWORD  fdwReason, \
    LPVOID  lpvReserved) \
{ \
```

DLLMAIN_ENTRY there is:

```
#define __rpc_macro_expand2(a, b) a##b
#define __rpc_macro_expand(a, b) __rpc_macro_expand2(a,b)
// ...
#define DLLMAIN_ENTRY __rpc_macro_expand(ENTRY_PREFIX, DllMain)
```